# Trouble understanding how to process C string

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to use Mac OS X's listxattr C function and turn it into something useful in Python. The man page tells me that the function returns a string buffer, which is a "simple NULL-terminated UTF-8 strings and are returned in arbitrary order. No extra padding is provided between names in the buffer."

In my C file, I have it set up correctly it seems (I hope):

```
  char buffer[size];
  res = listxattr("/path/to/file", buffer, size, options);
```

But when I got to print it, I only get the FIRST attribute ONLY, which was two characters long, even though its size is 25. So then I manually set buffer[3] = 'z' and low and behold when I print buffer again I get the first TWO attributes.

I think I understand what is going on. The buffer is a sequence of NULL-terminated strings, and stops printing as soon as it sees a NULL character. But then how am I supposed to unpack the entire sequence into ALL of the attributes?

I'm new to C and using it to figure out the mechanics of extending Python with C, and ran into this doozy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `char *p = buffer;`
2. get the length  with `strlen(p)`. If the length is 0, stop.
3. process the first chunk.
4. p = p + length + 1;
5. back to step 2.

Answer (score 1):

So you guessed pretty much right.

The listxattr function returns a bunch of null-terminated strings packed in next to each other.  Since strings (and arrays) in C are just blobs of memory, they don't carry around any extra information with them (such as their length).  The convention in C is to use a null character ('\0') to represent the end of a string.

Here's one way to traverse the list, in this case changing it to a comma-separated list.

```
int i = 0;
for (; i < res; i++)
   if (buffer[i] == '\0' && i != res -1) //we're in between strings
       buffer[i] = ',';
```

Of course, you'll want to make these into Python strings rather than just substituting in commas, but that should give you enough to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like listxattr returns the size of the buffer it has filled, so you can use that to help you. Here's an idea:

```
for(int i=0; i<res-1; i++)
{
    if( buffer[i] == 0 )
        buffer[i] = ',';
}
```

Now, instead of being separated by null characters, the attributes are separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since I'm going to send it to Python I don't have to process it C-style after all. Just use the Py_BuildValue passing it the format character s#, which knows what do with it. You'll also need the size.

```
return Py_BuildValue("s#", buffer, size);
```

You can process it into a list on Python's end using split('\x00'). I found this after trial and error, but I'm glad to have learned something about C.